# Visual Studio 2010 Kinetic/Smooth Scrolling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Is there a plugin to VS.NET 2010 that implements kinetic scrolling like on the iPhone?  Basically, I want the text editor in VS.NET to do kinetic/smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this adding could be interesting for you:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7860a6a7-d50c-488c-8bb5-e99d8ed057d2?SRC=Home

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it in .NET with [the demo linked on this MSDN post.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/5ffa4e4e-a766-4177-90c5-9d3373c7f6b6)

Comment: Thanks, but I want the text editor inside of VS.NET to have kinetic scrolling, not a WPF control that does kinetic scrolling.